# flask wtforms showing validation error on 2 forms on the same html page and same route/view

Tags: python, flask, django-forms, flask-wtforms, wtforms

So I have 2 forms, login form and registration form, on ***home.html***, which show up as a modal when clicked on the login button, which looks like as follows:

**home.html**

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-danger" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#loginModal">
Login
</button>

<div class="modal fade" id="loginModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
              <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                  <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Sign In</h5>
                  <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                  <button id="login" class="btn btn-login btn-md">Log In</button>
                  <button id="regis" class="btn btn-login btn-md">Register</button><hr style="margin-top: 0px;">
                  <div class="" id="login">
                      <form method="POST" action="">
                          {{ login_form.hidden_tag() }}
                          <fieldset class="form-group">
                              <div class="form-group">
                                  {% if login_form.email_login.errors %}
                                      {{ login_form.email_login(class="form-control form-control-md is-invalid") }}
                                      <div class="invalid-feedback">
                                          {% for error in login_form.email_login.errors %}
                                              <span>{{ error }}</span>
                                          {% endfor %}
                                      </div>
                                  {% else %}
                                      {{ login_form.email_login(class="form-control form-control-md mb-2", placeholder="Email") }}
                                  {% endif %}
                              </div>
                              <div class="form-group">
                                  {% if login_form.password_login.errors %}
                                      {{ login_form.password_login(class="form-control form-control-md is-invalid") }}
                                      <div class="invalid-feedback">
                                          {% for error in login_form.password_login.errors %}
                                              <span>{{ error }}</span>
                                          {% endfor %}
                                      </div>
                                  {% else %}
                                      {{ login_form.password_login(class="form-control form-control-md mb-2", placeholder="Password") }}
                                  {% endif %}
                              </div>
                              <div class="form-check">
                                  {{ login_form.remember(class="form-check-input") }}
                                  {{ login_form.remember.label(class="form-check-label") }}
                              </div>
                          </fieldset>
                          <div class="form-group">
                              {{ login_form.submit_login(class="btn btn-danger") }}
                              <small class="text-muted ml-2">
                                  <a href="">Forgot Password?</a>
                              </small>
                          </div>
                      </form>
                  </div>
                  <div class="" id="regis">
                      <form method="POST" action="">
                          {{ regis_form.hidden_tag() }}
                          <fieldset class="form-group">
                              <div class="form-group">              
                                  {% if regis_form.username_regis.errors %}
                                      {{ regis_form.username_regis(class="form-control form-control-md is-invalid") }}
                                      <div class="invalid-feedback">
                                          {% for error in regis_form.username_regis.errors %}
                                              <span>{{ error }}</span>
                                          {% endfor %}
                                      </div>
                                  {% else %}
                                      {{ regis_form.username_regis(class="form-control form-control-md mb-2", placeholder="Username") }}
                                  {% endif %}
                              </div>
                              <div class="form-group">
                                  {% if regis_form.email_regis.errors %}
                                      {{ regis_form.email_regis(class="form-control form-control-md is-invalid") }}
                                      <div class="invalid-feedback">
                                          {% for error in regis_form.email_regis.errors %}
                                              <span>{{ error }}</span>
                                          {% endfor %}
                                      </div>
                                  {% else %}
                                      {{ regis_form.email_regis(class="form-control form-control-md mb-2", placeholder="Email") }}
                                  {% endif %}
                              </div>
                              <div class="form-group">
                                  {% if regis_form.password_regis.errors %}
                                      {{ regis_form.password_regis(class="form-control form-control-md is-invalid") }}
                                      <div class="invalid-feedback">
                                          {% for error in regis_form.password_regis.errors %}
                                              <span>{{ error }}</span>
                                          {% endfor %}
                                      </div>
                                  {% else %}
                                      {{ regis_form.password_regis(class="form-control form-control-md mb-2", placeholder="Password") }}
                                  {% endif %}
                              </div>

                          </fieldset>
                          <div class="form-group">
                              {{ regis_form.submit_regis(class="btn btn-danger") }}
                          </div>
                      </form>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
```

The two "Log In" and "Register" buttons are tabs i.e. by clicking on "Register" button you will see registration form and vice versa which is controlled by JavaScript.

My ***forms.py*** file looks like this:

**forms.py**

```
class RegistrationForm(FlaskForm):
    username_regis = StringField('Username',
                           validators=[DataRequired(), Length(min=2, max=20)])
    email_regis = StringField('Email',
                        validators=[DataRequired(), Email()])
    password_regis = PasswordField('Password', validators=[DataRequired()])
    submit_regis = SubmitField('Sign Up')



class LoginForm(FlaskForm):
    email_login = StringField('Email',
                        validators=[DataRequired(), Email()])
    password_login = PasswordField('Password', validators=[DataRequired()])
    remember = BooleanField('Remember Me')
    submit_login = SubmitField('Login')
```

and below is the ***routes.py*** function:

**routes.py**

```
@app.route("/", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def home():
    login_form = LoginForm()
    regis_form = RegistrationForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if login_form.validate_on_submit() and login_form.submit_login.data:
            user = User.query.filter_by(email=login_form.email_login.data).first()
            if user and bcrypt.check_password_hash(user.password, login_form.password_login.data):
                login_user(user, remember=login_form.remember.data)
                next_page = request.args.get('next')
                return redirect(next_page) if next_page else redirect(url_for('home'))
            else:
                flash('Login Unsuccessful. Please check email and password', 'danger')
        if regis_form.validate_on_submit() and regis_form.submit_regis.data:
            hashed_password = bcrypt.generate_password_hash(regis_form.password_regis.data).decode('utf-8')
            user = User(username=regis_form.username_regis.data, email=regis_form.email_regis.data, password=hashed_password)
            db.session.add(user)
            db.session.commit()
            flash('Your account has been created! You are now able to log in', 'success')
            return redirect(url_for('home'))
    return render_template('home.html', login_form=login_form, regis_form=regis_form)
```

Now, The problem is that when I try to login using an email that is not registered it flashes me
*'Login Unsuccessful. Please check email and password'*
which is ok as it should do this. but when I open the login modal again and open the registration tab, the * username_regis password_regis and email_regis* fields are showing me 'The field is required' error.

It should not show me this error on registration form because I never submitted this form.

I want to get rid of these error messages. I will deeply appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you wrote is as follows:

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    if login_form.validate_on_submit() and login_form.submit_login.data:
        <SNIP>
    if regis_form.validate_on_submit() and regis_form.submit_regis.data:
        <SNIP>
```

That means that *both* forms are are validated, no matter what form you submit. So when you submit one form the other will always show errors. The *preferred* solution is to post to  different routes. On your form the `action` parameter will need to be filled and you will need two functions, one for each route. You than will also get rid of asking if form data is available. It must be, because you are on that route.

Comment: How are both forms submitted? I have named both submit buttons differently. Is that a flask thing or my mistake? I can post this to different routes but what if I specifically want it this way? Is your preferred solution the only solution?

Comment: the method says validate on submit. when I don't submit it, it shouldn't validate and give me those errors. Is this doesn't work like this?

Comment: Flask does not know what form has been submitted. The browser tells what action to take, not what is submitted. By your code you are telling it that on a post on this route it can expect the fields of both forms. That is not so. validate_on_submit is called that because _you_ are saying it should expect the fields of that form.